# how to reset root password by ansible

Tags: ansible

we have the servers where root passwd needs to be reset by ansible.

I ran the command below to get the hash passwd and input our correct root passwd:

```py
python3 -c 'import crypt,getpass;pw=getpass.getpass();print(crypt.crypt(pw) if (pw==getpass.getpass("Confirm: ")) else exit())'
Password:
Confirm:
$6$c/98MRPOs7JQ.pbw$XI7Qyz80d5ZV2DcgMk8limxB9DoTNsTCIZVYtLRTkM3a5T6NnHOgxEoRq/te4jIJhm114HuTXLv0dMf5H
```

then, I added that generated root password in my playbook:

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: Change user password
      user: name=root update_password=always password=$6$c/98MRPOs7JQ.pbw$XI7Qyz80d5ZV2DcgMk8limxB9DoTNsTCIZVYtLRTkM3a5T6NnHOgxEoRq/te4jIJhm114HuTXLv0dMf5H
```

ran that playbook without errors, then tried to login with that actual (not hash encrypted) root password on the server, but it does not work, what I am doing wrong and how it can be fixed ?

Comment: perhaps try quoting content of `password`, like `password='foobarzoo...'` ...untested guess.

Comment: I did try it - not working

Answer (score 1):

Your hash is probably not correct. Maybe an incompatible hashing-algorithm was used.
There are [multiple ways to generate that hash](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-generate-encrypted-passwords-for-the-user-module):

The ansible-way:
`ansible all -i localhost, -m debug -a "msg={{ 'mypassword' | password_hash('sha512', 'mysecretsalt') }}"`

The `mkpasswd`:
`mkpasswd --method=sha-512`

Or with python:
`python -c "from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt; import getpass; print(sha512_crypt.using(rounds=5000).hash(getpass.getpass()))"`
You need to install `passlib` first.